# Extracting Data and creating a new column of repetitive values

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, stringr

I'm gathering some data using a script like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

foo_matrix <- read_html("#address")

test <- foo_matrix %>%  
html_nodes(#Retrieval Information) %>%
html_text() %>%
str_trim
```

The output it returns looks like this:

> ```
> [1] "Red Team"             "Mike Johnson"         "QB"                      "6-1"                    "191"                   
>     [6] "99"                 "21"                     "2"                      "5"                      "Joe Smith"          
>     [11] "OT"                     "6-3"                    "290"                    "98"                 "55"                    
>     [16] "3"                      "1"
> ```

What I want to do is extract that first value in the string ("Red Team") then take the remaining data to create an eight column matrix as such:

```
Mike Johnson QB 6-1 191 99 21 2 5
Joe Smith    OT 6-3 290 98 55 3 1
```

But then I want to create a ninth column that takes the value from the initially extracted string and applies it to all the rows so the end result looks like:

```
Mike Johnson MD 6-1 191 99 21 2 5 Red Team
Joe Smith    VA 6-3 290 98 55 3 1 Red Team
```

What would be the best approach to a.) extract the value and to then b.) loop it across all the rows as a ninth column?

Comment: Could you provide the url to reproduce your example?

Comment: @ANG I would love to, but unfortunately, I cannot post it publicly for privacy reasons (the output results is just dummy data, though structurally that's what it looks like).

Comment: @ANG is there a way you can private message people? If that's possible, feel free to do so, and I can share it there. I'm just not putting it out in public.

Answer (score 0):

There may be cleaner ways to do it.

You can first separate the team from people data, assuming the team is always
the first element.

Then assuming your people data will have always 8 columns, you can `split` them in a list and convert the result in a unique data.frame using `as_tibble` and `bind_rows` .

Finally, you add the team with `add_column`. `mutate` should also do the trick.

```r
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)


data <- c("Red Team", "Mike Johnson", "QB" ,"6-1","191",               
 "99" ,"21" ,"2","5","Joe Smith" ,     
 "OT" ,"6-3" , "290" , "98" ,"55",      
 "3"  ,"1")

team <- data[1]
people <- data[-1]

resulting_df <- people %>%  
  split(ceiling(seq_along(people)/8)) %>% 
  map(~ as_tibble(t(.x))) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  add_column(team = team)

resulting_df
#> # A tibble: 2 x 9
#>   V1           V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    team    
#>   <chr>        <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   
#> 1 Mike Johnson QB    6-1   191   99    21    2     5     Red Team
#> 2 Joe Smith    OT    6-3   290   98    55    3     1     Red Team
```